# Is there any need to check the block name when my module just define a block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I am reading "Drupal 7 Module Development", and I followed the book's steps to create a block in my module.

```
/**
   * Implements hook_block_info().
   */
  function first_block_hook_info() {
    $block = array();

    $block['list_modules'] = array(
      'info' => t('A listing of all the enable modules'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
    );

    return $block;
  }
  /**
  * Implements hook_block_view()
  */
  function first_block_view($block_name ='') {
    if ($block_name == 'list_modules') {
      $list = module_list();

      $theme_args = array('items' => $list, 'type' => 'ol');
      $content = theme('item_list', $theme_args);

      $block = array(
        'subject' => t('Enable modules'),
        'content' => $content
      );

      return $block;
    }
  }
```

`first_block_view($block_name = '')` is using `if ($block_name == 'list_modules')` to check which block should be rendered, but I think Drupal will only send  list_modules' to my module.

Is there any need to check the block name in `hook_block_view()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your module defines only a single block, technically no, it's not necessary.

But, as soon as you want to add another block, you'll need to distinguish between that and the existing one, so you'll need to check the block delta.

It's a good practice to get into, even if it's not *strictly* necessary to test the delta in the block view function.

Comment: One more question, I can not find the block( ```'list_module'```) in **Blocks** page, How can I enable the block? thanks.

Comment: The title is whatever comes under the `info` key in `hook_block_info()`...so it'll be called "A listing of all the enable modules" in your case. You can always change `info` to something shorter, and use the `description` key to describe it in more detail. You'll need to clear the caches after doing that for the change to get picked up

Comment: Can I disable caches when develop module?

Comment: Certainly can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892573/drupal-7-how-to-completely-disable-cache